# Django+docker compose+NGINX+aws+RDS+postgreSQL deployment and ports flow

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, port

Hi I developed a simple personal blog with Django and Nginx as a reverse proxy server and want to deploy It with AWS in the most costo effettive way. Which Is It? And I don't understand the ports flow between localhost, Django (uwsgi+gunicorn), Nginx, docker (compose), postgrSQL and AWS RDS...can someone give me help or advice on this?

Other infos (this is how I imagined it and tried to put all in a flow but I think there's something wrong, and sorry for the bad formatting but I didn't know ho to do it, i'm a beginner coder):

AWS RDS’s endpoint:5432

Client’s requests(incoming/inbound traffic):80 <-- LB(Load Balancer):8000 <-- Nginx <-- (Gunicorn + uwsgi (django app/web container)) 0.0.0.0:8000:9000 <-- docker container:8000 <-- (localhost(0.0.0.0):8000 <-- Gunicorn) django_app:8000 <-- uwsgi:9000 <-- Nginx80:8000 <-- load balancer:8000 (defaults traffic from listener HTTP port 80 redirect to 443 (HTTPS) and then from this to TG1):8000 <-- TG1(Target Group 1) <-- TG2 <-- Client

Some debugging logs:

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up

nginx_1  | 2023/06/02 15:20:44 [error] 10#10: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://172.18.0.3:9000", host: "wpad.homenet.telecomitalia.it"
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2023:15:20:44 +0000] "GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "WinHttp-Autoproxy-Service/5.1" "-"

$ docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "blog-database-1.c4jwuoj8a300.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com  # db endpoint" to address: Name or service not known

My docker-compose-prod.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .   
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/vol/web
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DJANGO_DEBUG=False
    env_file:
      - .env
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    env_file:
      - .env
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx  
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web    
    ports:
      - 80:8000   
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/vol/static


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine
LABEL maintainer="underthemist.com"


COPY ./nginx.conf.tpl /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.tpl
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
COPY ./run.sh run.sh

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000

ENV APP_HOST=web

ENV APP_PORT=9000


USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static && \
    chmod 755 /vol/static && \
    touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chmod +x /run.sh

VOLUME /vol/static

USER nginx

CMD [ "/run.sh" ]
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
upstream django {
    server web:8000;
}


    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};
    charset     utf-8;



    location /media  {
        alias /vol/media;
    }
    
   
    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Please someone can help me with correct configuration of servers?

Comment: You would not run both a PostgreSQL docker container **and** use AWS RDS. You would use one or the other. They are two completely separate ways of running a database. You don't setup a "port flow" between them somehow, you simply get rid of the PostgreSQL container if you want to use RDS.